# Why I can not send data to non-contract address?

Tags: transactions

I use Ganache to test,the code is as follow：

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
const Utils = require('web3-utils');

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));}
let txTransfer = {};
txTransfer.from = web3.eth.accounts[0];
txTransfer.to = web3.eth.accounts[1];
txTransfer.value = 4000000;
txTransfer.data = Utils.toHex('free text data');
txTransfer.gas = 1000000;
console.log(txTransfer);
web3.eth.sendTransaction(txTransfer);
```

Comment: The wrong message is:Attempting to run transaction which calls a contract function, but recipient address is not a contract address

Comment: What's your command-line arguments for Ganache?

Comment: I use Ganache with GUI，just simply open it

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is an oddity of Ganache. It rejects any transaction with a non-empty `data` field if the recipient is not a contract (or `0x0`).

https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core/blob/c7a2f69cad6bd8d73a67c300e8eb9816b44d694c/lib/statemanager.js#L837

I would suggest filing an issue on GitHub. This behavior does not match how Ethereum proper works. You should be able to send `data` with any transaction. I would consider this incompatibility a bug.